# Retro sega saturn's "Gouraud shading"

Tags: shaders

[image: the shading]

I've been trying to replicate this for myself for a while now and I can't seem to get through...
I'm a blender beginner btw, 2nd week user.

Is there some way to replicate gouraud shading like in this game here?:
https://youtu.be/60F44ec-VjM

Yes I know that that I'm supposed to use "smooth shading" and that one "N64 shading" thread that gets referenced to me a lot but I have trouble replicating how they do it anyways, is there some way to replicate this type of shading? Please lemme know, thanks.

Comment: The only way I know to do this without modifying the blender source code would be to write an OpenGL Shader Language (GLSL) shader as described in [this webpage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Blender/Specular_Highlights) .

Comment: Hi, @MartyFouts that series of articles appears to use the game engine? Is it possible to write GLSL shaders straight into the viewport?

Comment: @RobinBetts Oops.  I confused myself.  You can create [Open Shader Language (OSL)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/osl.html) as shader nodes; but I was wrong in believing you could also create GLSL nodes.

Comment: @MartyFouts ahh, shame. I can't think of a way of doing this other than baking  into vertex-colors.. that's not to say there isn't one. It's an interesting problem. After all, I've seen an entire renderer written in OSL, somewhere. Maybe you have to make your own in-scene screen.